# Is it possible to change character map of keyboard in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I want to know if there is a way to change character map of keyboard in MS Word? For example when I press A it types B and vice versa.
Thanks.

Comment: What an odd request.  What exactly are you trying to change? And what version of Windows and Word do you have?

Comment: Cbn you ae more specific?

Comment: In fact I write a Persian doc and in Persian we should use zero-width non-joiner (ZWNJ) character in many cases. It is a special character and so I have created a short-key (Ctrl+Space) for it (from Insert Symbol). But I am thinking to replace it with a non-usually used character like as '`'. To just press one key on keyboard!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Character Map tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_Map) allowing you to choose special symbols might not be modifiable in the way you requested. However it looks like you might be talking about changing **keyboard layout**.

It is possible to **create custom keyboard layout** using [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx). You can add custom symbols and remap all keys.

This new layout will work not only in Microsoft Word, but in any other application. You could have standard layout to use in other applications, and then change to your custom layout when you are working in Microsoft Word.

For adding extra symbols or [zero-width non-joiner (ZWNJ)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_non-joiner) I suggest using third or fourth level characters (via [AltGr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key)). Thus keeping all symbols from original layout intact.

Comment: +1 yes i've used MSKLC before. And you can change language-layout(don't recall exactly which) in the toolbar, or with a keyboard shortcut. MSKLC is very flexible.  It may be a bit much, but it's flexible/powerful.  Weaker programs may only be able to swap one key with another but I think MSKLC can do any character.